# how to get refresh token for angularx-social-login in angular8

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-social-login

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularx-social-login)

Hi i am using `angularx-social-login` of version `2.2.1` in Angular8 application. Here as google auth token expires by 1 hour, i have to call method for refresh token. I have been through many websites but not able to get solution. I have installed and declared in app module and now using in login component to get the auth token and email address, id from sign in google button click. But i am not getting how to call refresh method for expiration time near by. Please help.

HTML:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" (click)="signInWithGoogle()">Sign in with Google</button>
```

Ts:

```
public signInWithGoogle(): void {
    let socialUser = this.oauthService.signIn(GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID).then((userData) => {
      if(userData.idToken){
      
      } else {
        alert('danger')
      }
   });
  }
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { SocialLoginModule, AuthServiceConfig } from "angularx-social-login";
import { GoogleLoginProvider } from "angularx-social-login";

 imports: [
    SocialLoginModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: AuthServiceConfig,
      useFactory: provideConfig
    }],

let config = new AuthServiceConfig([
  {
    id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    provider: new GoogleLoginProvider("1051927480520-u87cv859uap5e6t4r5f52mk96a8a6nhe.apps.googleusercontent.com")
  },
]);

export function provideConfig() {
  return config;
}
```

so from demo, i am able to get details of gmail account i choosed for, but token expires by an hour, i need to get refresh token before it expires. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this question is relevant anymore however `SocialAuthService` from `angularx-social-login` package actually exposes method to do this - `refreshAuthToken(providerId: string): Promise<void>;`

You can simply do e.g.:

```
refreshUserToken() {
    this.socialAuthService.refreshAuthToken(GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID).then(() => {
      // Any post-refresh actions if needed
    });
  }
```

or:

```
async refreshUserToken() {
    await this.socialAuthService.refreshAuthToken(GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID);
  }
```

and if you're already subscribed to `authState` changes you will get a new `SocialUser` (with new, refreshed `authToken`) after refreshing. See this method [implementation](https://github.com/abacritt/angularx-social-login/blob/6f0a0ce52d0009159e92db474f1ef37c76b770f4/projects/lib/src/socialauth.service.ts#L104) on Github.

Disclaimer: Looking at the implementation it woks only for Google log in.